# How should a graphic pattern be packaged and sold as a digital download?

Tags: patterns, designers

I've learned how to make a seamless digital pattern and since then I've been practicing. I feel like I could possibly sell these patterns but I am not sure how I should go about selling my patterns. Below is an image of my design from Society6; these are the types of patterns I am referring to.

Should I sell the .ai file? Should I sell it as a high quality 300ppi jpeg?

I've tried to find others doing what I want but the closest I get is seeing people on Etsy selling paper patterns and they sell them as 12" x 12", high quality 300ppi images.

I don't know where else to find answers.

What would be a professional way to package and sell graphic design patterns? Thank you for any help.

[image]

Comment: Selling products with your patterns would probably give you a much wider range of clients. Here are some services where you can print and sell things: http://www.creativebloq.com/career/sell-design-online-912746

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is preety intresting and every one has this question when they start working online.But here's the fact, you should think as the customers point of view.

Sell your designs to customers according to the customers requirement like the shutterstock do they sell a different range of single product so there rate varies.

**Smaller image or Resolution = lesser price**

**large image or Resolution = More price**

**and Original file = For Best price**

So I recommend you to create a different range for you design and sell them accordingly as I stated above.
But before doing that copyright your Design so the other people can't buy form you and sell to others

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question comes down to **where** you want to sell your digital item whether it is a digital marketplace or your own website.

For example, on GraphicRiver, authors of digital items are encouraged to include a pattern design in commonly known file formats so that both beginners and more experienced buyers can open the file and use it.

Look at this specific example: http://graphicriver.net/item/christmas-seamless-knitting-pattern-set/13403553?s_phrase=&s_rank=12

If you look at the "**Graphics Files Included**" section, you will see that the author of this item included the pattern in JPG Image, Vector EPS, and AI Illustrator file formats.

However, if you are going to sell a digital item on your own website make sure to include the file in **as many formats as possible** so that anyone who buys it can open it. If you are going to include an image file, make sure it is in high resolution and 300 ppi like you said.

Once you saved the file in as many formats as possible, compress all of them in a .ZIP file which any computer can open and it will be ready to be sold online.

Answer (score 0):

As AAGD's comment recommends, there's lot of websites that offer you to open your own online shop and offer your line of products (eg. Zazzle, Cafepress and... Society6). The benefit is that you get to customize your own products, there's usually no fee for you, you don't need to have any inventory and you don't actually sell any native file; therefore people cannot really copy them.

You could also consider selling your patterns as Stock Images (istock, 123rf, dreamstime <---this last one, I don't really recommend). Your vectors will be valuable to some designers and it can be a passive income very easy to manage. Simply look for stock image sites online and see how you can join and what are the terms.

I wouldn't recommend selling vectors directly from your own website. There's some benefits in using a third party for this; you don't need to manage the hosting and distribution yourself, and you get some protection on your artworks. It's not always easy to sell digital files online. For example: People who decide to buy your image from a stock image website might need to purchase a commercial license as well to redistribute your art. Another example: People will hardly be able to share a download link of your file after purchasing it (that's usually a challenge with selling digital files.)

If you do decide to sell your design packages yourself, you should definitely consider Rishab.Ag's answer, and create different package price as he suggested.

The point is: if you plan to sell patterns to be used by others on their own products, stock image sites is probably the best option for you. And at this point, why not gain some visibility by actually selling the products yourself since you are the artist who did these patterns! Also, working in vector is definitely the right thing to do.